# Kafka KStream - measuring consumer lag

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Since my **KStream** based application doesn't follow the traditional Kafka Consumer route how should I keep track of consumer lag? Normally I'd use [ConsumerOffsetChecker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-CanIpredicttheresultsoftheconsumerrebalance?)  (or something of that ilk) but it requires a consumer group name.

What should I use instead?

(I want to track this so I can tell if / when to launch new consumers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Streams leverages `KafkaConsumer` internally, and uses the application ID as consumer group ID. Thus, you can monitor the lag the same way as for any other consumer.

See http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#required-configuration-parameters

> Application Id (application.id): Each stream processing application must have a unique id. [...]
>
> This id is used in the following places to isolate resources used by the application from others:
>
> - As the default Kafka consumer and producer client.id prefix
> - **As the Kafka consumer group.id for coordination**
> - As the name of the sub-directory in the state directory (cf. state.dir)
> - As the prefix of internal Kafka topic names

Comment: That's v strange. When I call `kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper <zookeeper ip:2181> --list` it returns nothing. If I specify the **group** (my application id) and `--describe` I get a `no topic available for consumer group provided`.

Comment: Since Kafka 0.9 consumer groups are not managed via ZK anymore. Thus, you need to specify different flags: `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server <broker-host:port> --list`

Comment: Yes, ZK is still required. However, for future releases, clients (and thus Streams application) will not depend on ZK anymore -- not sure for which release though exactly.

Comment: To clarify: The ZK dependency of Kafka Streams in Kafka 0.10.0 is/was only temporary gap filler until Kafka's KIP-4 functionality is officially available (KIP-4 is already merged in Kafka `trunk`) because we didn't want to duplicate the effort (of KIP-4) to perform topic management in Kafka Streams without ZK, as we were aware that KIP-4 would soon be ready.  Now that the latter is ready for use, Kafka Streams can get rid of its initial ZK dependency, which we are already working on.